# Identify position in each list element when one value becomes greater than another

Tags: r

I have a list, `lprobs`. Each list element is a simple vector of probabilities (P[Z≥z]) under different parameter values (defined below in `kvec`).

When comparing these probabilities, the lower parameter value initially always has a lower probability when z>=2. Then there is a "crossover" at some value of z where the lower parameter value begins yielding a higher probability. I need to determine the the z value and probability when these crossovers occur for all combinations of k values.

The following plot may help visualize this:

[image: probs plot]

The black (k = 0.01) is the easiest example to point out: I need to find the z value and P(Z=z) when P(Z=z) for k = 0.01 crosses over with k = 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 (somewhere after z > 300). If there is not a crossover by the maximum z value (defined in the below code by `cutoff`), it should return `NA` (i.e. when comparing k values of 0.01 and 0.25).

I have tried several `for` loops and manually finding these values, but I have not found an elegant solution to systematically record the z value and probability for each crossover. The actual data are much larger.

The desired result would be as below (though open to suggestions, doesn't have to be exactly this), where `z_val` and `prob_z` identify the specific z value and probability of each crossover event:

```
## putting 1234 as a dummy z value and 0.567 as dummy probability 

want <- data.frame(expand.grid(kvec, kvec), z_val = 1234, prob_z = 0.567)
want <- want[want[,1] != want[,2],c(2:1,3:4)]
colnames(want)[1:2] <- c("k1", "k2")

#    k1   k2    z_val prob_z
# 2  0.01 0.25  1234  0.567
# 3  0.01 0.50  1234  0.567
# 4  0.01 0.75  1234  0.567
# 5  0.01 1.00  1234  0.567
#...
# 21 1.00 0.01  1234  0.567
# 22 1.00 0.25  1234  0.567
# 23 1.00 0.50  1234  0.567
# 24 1.00 0.75  1234  0.567
```

The data to recreate these probabilities and the figure is here:

```
## Functions to calculate probabilities
clprob <- function(R, k, z, n = 1){
  lnumer = log(n) + lgamma(k*z+z-n) + (z-n)*(log(R)-log(k))  
  ldenom = log(z) + lgamma(k*z) + lgamma(z-n+1) + (k*z+z-n)*(log(k+R)-log(k))  
  return(exp(lnumer - ldenom))
}
clcdf <- function(R, k, z, n = 1){
  1-sum(clprob(R,k,1:(z-1),n))
}

# Define parameters
kvec <- c(0.01, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0) 
cutoff <- 500
clsize <- 2:cutoff 

# List to store probabilities
lprobs <- lapply(kvec, function(x) sapply(clsize, clcdf, R = 0.90, k = x))

# Plot
plot(NA, xlim = c(2, cutoff), ylim = c(1e-3, 1), log = 'y', 
     ylab = expression("P[Z">="z] (log scale)"), xlab = expression("z (">="2)"))
for (i in 1:length(lprobs)){points(lprobs[[i]], pch = 19, col = i, cex = 0.25)}
legend("topright", legend = paste("k =", kvec), col=1:length(kvec), pch=16, bty='n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
names(lprobs) = kvec
result = as.data.frame(cbind(
  t(combn(kvec,2)),
  t(sapply(combn(kvec,2, simplify = F), function(x) {
      zval = which(lprobs[[as.character(x[1])]] >= lprobs[[as.character(x[2])]])[1]
      prob = lprobs[[as.character(x[1])]][zval]
      return(c(zval,prob))}))
))
names(result) = c("k1", "k2", "z_val", "prob_z")
```

Output:

```
     k1   k2 z_val      prob_z
1  0.01 0.25    NA          NA
2  0.01 0.50   426 0.002858335
3  0.01 0.75   362 0.003171162
4  0.01 1.00   328 0.003373438
5  0.25 0.50   144 0.013438024
6  0.25 0.75   128 0.015014513
7  0.25 1.00   119 0.016052089
8  0.50 0.75   104 0.019002732
9  0.50 1.00    98 0.020167960
10 0.75 1.00    88 0.022700673
```

As the above shows, the black line (0.01) never crosses the red line (0.25). The black line does cross the light blue line (1.00) at Z=328.